# Right Triangle CMD tool

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x, console

I was most interested in feedback on the overall approach to the problem, naming conventions, efficiency, etc.

- I would like to avoid using argparse/docopt or something similar, unless it would have a *major* impact on complexity of the program.
- Any tips on how should I go about adding help-dialogues for ease of use?

---

```
from collections import OrderedDict as oDct
from trianglesolver import solve, degree
from termcolor import colored, cprint
import numpy as np
import cmd



def prntDct(dct):
    for k, v in dct.items(): print(k + ' =', v)


def noNones(*args):
    return False if any(arg is None for arg in args) else True


def argify(string_in, ref_dict):
    fin = ref_dict.copy()
    string = string_in.replace(' ', ', ')
    temp = eval('dict({})'.format(string))
    matched = {k: temp[k] for k in temp if k in fin}
    fin.update(matched)
    return fin


def solvify(items):
    a,b,c,A,B,C = items

    if A is not None: A = A * degree
    if B is not None: B = B * degree
    C = C * degree

    try:
        if a is None: outs = solve(c=c, b=b, C=C)
        elif b is None: outs = solve(a=a, c=c, C=C)
        elif c is None: outs = solve(a=a, b=b, C=C)

    except:
        if noNones(a, A): outs = solve(a=a, A=A,C=C)
        elif noNones(a, B): outs = solve(a=a, B=B, C=C)
        elif noNones(b, A): outs = solve(b=b, A=A, C=C)
        elif noNones(b, B): outs = solve(b=b, B=B, C=C)
        elif noNones(c, A): outs = solve(c=c, A=A, C=C)
        elif noNones(c, B): outs = solve(c=c, B=B, C=C)

    finally:
        a,b,c,A,B,C = outs
        return ([a, b, c, A / degree, B / degree, C / degree])


def triangify(items, output_format, prec, scale=None, side='c'):
    a,b,c,A,B,C = solvify(items)

    if side is 'c': ordr = [a, b, c] + ['a', 'b', 'c']; set = [0,1]
    if side is 'b': ordr = [c, a, b] + ['c', 'a', 'b']; set = [1,2]
    if side is 'a': ordr = [c, b, a] + ['c', 'b', 'a']; set = [2,1]

    if scale is not None:
        sides_arrange = np.array(ordr[:3])
        sides_scaling = sides_arrange / ordr[2]
        sVals  = (sides_scaling * scale).tolist()
    else: sVals = ordr[:3]

    sKeys = ordr[3:]

    P = np.sum(sVals)
    S = (sVals[set[0]] * sVals[set[1]]) / 2

    fKeys = sKeys + ['A','B','C','P','S']
    toVals = sVals + [A,  B,  C,  P,  S]

    if type(prec) is int: fVals = np.around(np.array(toVals),prec)
    else: fVals = (np.around(np.array(toVals), 0)).astype(int)

    triangle = oDct(zip(fKeys, fVals))

    if output_format is 'all': output_format = 'abcABCPS'

    fin = {k: triangle[k] for k in list(output_format) if k in triangle}

    return fin



def main():
    scalar = ScalarCmd()
    print('\n' * 4)
    cprint('Triangle Scalar Tool', 'cyan')
    cprint('====================', 'cyan')
    print()
    cprint('type "help" for commands', 'cyan')
    print()
    scalar.ruler = colored('-', 'cyan')
    scalar.cmdloop()



defaults = oDct([
    ('P', None),
    ('S', None),
    ('a', None),
    ('b', None),
    ('c', None),
    ('A', None),
    ('B', None),
    ('C', 90),
    ('prec', 2),
    ('scale', 1),
    ('side', 'c'),
    ('output', 'all')])


class ScalarCmd(cmd.Cmd):
    prompt = (colored('\n>', 'green') + colored(' ', 'white'))

    def default(self, arg):
        print('invalid command, try typing "help"')

    def do_quit(self, arg):
        '''exits the program'''
        cprint('\nexiting...\n', 'red')
        exit()


    def do_solve(self, arg):
        '''type at least 2 sides or angles\n'''

        error = ['',
            'invalid command:',  # most of these docstrings are temps
            'type at least 2 sides named a/b/c or angles named A/B/C',
            'usage: TBD','']

        try:
            if len(arg) < 2:
                error[0] = '\nempty command:'
                raise

            else:
                args = argify(arg, defaults)

                sides_angles = list(args.values())[2:8]

                outs = triangify(
                    sides_angles,
                    args['output'],
                    args['prec'])

                print()
                prntDct(outs)
                print()  # <- easy blank lines

        except Exception:
            print(*error, sep='\n')
            return

    def do_scale(self, arg):
        '''type at least 2 sides or angles\n'''

        error = ['',
            'invalid command:',
            'type at least 2 sides named a/b/c or angles named A/B/C',
            'usage: TBD','']

        try:
            if len(arg) < 2:
                error[0] = '\nempty command:'
                raise

            else:
                args = argify(arg, defaults)

                sides_angles = list(args.values())[2:8]

                outs = triangify(
                    sides_angles,
                    args['output'],
                    args['prec'],
                    args['scale'],
                    args['side'])

                print()
                prntDct(outs)
                print()  # <- easy blank lines

        except Exception:
            print(*error, sep='\n')
            return



if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

I'm still quite an amateur with python programming, so I thank you in advance for your feedback!

Answer (score 4):

### General

- Personally I would prefer putting the clauses if `if` and `else` statements on separate lines even if they are only one line long.
- You should avoid using a generic `except` without specifying an exception or using a generic `Exception`. Instead, you should catch the specific exception you expect the code to throw. Otherwise, you may end up catching `TypeError` or some other exception that indicates a bug and that should be propagated instead of caught. From PEP 8:

  > A good rule of thumb is to limit use of bare 'except' clauses to two cases:
  >
  > 1. If the exception handler will be printing out or logging the traceback; at least the user will be aware that an error has occurred.
  > 2. If the code needs to do some cleanup work, but then lets the exception propagate upwards with raise. try...finally can be a better way to handle this case.
- The `main` method should be at the end, just before the `if __name__=="__main__"` statement.

### Triangle Solver

- `solvify` should return a tuple instead of a list since each index has a specific meaning.
- `argify` should not use `eval`; instead parse the input string directly.
- Use the equality operator (`side=='c'`) instead of the `is` keyword for comparing strings.
- Use `isinstance` for type checks, as in `if isinstance(prec,int)` instead of `if type(prec) is int`

### ScalarCmd

- This should be refactored into a separate file to separate the UI and the backend.
- `try`...`raise` inside `do_solve` has no exception to raise.
- I am not sure if this is possible using `termcolor` but the `cmd.Cmd.cmdloop()` has an `intro` parameter that can be used for printing the intro banner.

For more information about Python style conventions [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) is a good place to start.

Comment: what do you mean by "parse the input string directly"?

Comment: You should write some code to parse the string passed in via `string_in` instead of using `eval`.

Answer (score 3):

Your choice of variable names is strange. There is no reason to leave out the `i` in `print` and `dict`, but keep it in `argify` and `solvify`. Be consistent and keep them all, or, ltrntvly, rmv ll th vwls.